# How to show depth of a single field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, frameworks

I am using `depth = 1` on my serializer to show details of a foreign key field. However, it is also showing details of another foreign key field which I don't really need. How do I show the details of one field but not the other one?

Comment: i think you can't do that with `depth`, from my experience, I always customise the foreign key field with another serialiser, not using `depth` then you can control which field will be shown with detail, and which field would not.

Comment: Thanks @Enix. Would you please give me a reference that I can follow to do what you just explained?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for your reference

Suppose you have three models:

```
class User(model.Model):
    username = model.CharField('username', max_length=10)

class Question(model.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=10)

class Answer(model.Model):
    user = model.ForeignKey(User)
    question = model.ForeignKey(Question)
    body = model.TextField('the answer body')
```

And you need to serialise `Answer`, with showing the detail of `Question`, but not showing the detail of `User`, then you could define your serialisers like that:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = []

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = QuestionSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude = []
```

when you serialise `Answer` with `AnswerSerializer`, you will notice that `question` field is serialise at the same time, however `user` field is still an integer without serialising.

If you need to serialise a foreign key, you can define a field in the serializer explicitly, and the field name equal to the field name in `model`, and the value is equal to Foreign key model serializer. When the model is serialise, `Answer` in this case, the foreign key field, `question` for this case, will be "expanded" with `QuestionSerializer`, and other foreign key fields still keep the origin foreign key value, `user` in this case, if you haven't explicitly defined a serializer field in the serializer.

Hope it would help.

Comment: Also works without the `exclude=[]` bits and with `fields = '__all__'`, by just "overwriting" the field we want to assign a custom serializer to.